# Where in the ruby doc is string.chars defined?

Tags: ruby, string, char, chars

I've been learning ruby by solving project euler problems and in one solution to a problem I saw you could do something like `"12341".chars.inject(1) { |prod, n| prod * n.to_i }`.

I've looked on the ruby doc but I can't find where `String#chars` is defined.

Can anyone explain how that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't present in 1.8.6, which is what you get if you look at http://ruby-doc.org/core/, but it's present in the [1.8.7](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000777) and [1.9 documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9/classes/String.html#M000248).

`String#chars` simply returns an [Enumerator](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable/Enumerator.html) (a class that provides the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html) interface) which yields each of the characters of the string in turn. This allows you to call [`inject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Enumerable.html#M003129) which will iterate over each of the items in the Enumerable, applying a block to that item and a value in which you collect results. In this case, you start with the value `1`, and on each iteration multiply the value by the integer value of each character.

Comment: It is listed in the 1.8.7 documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/String.html#M000777

Comment: Ah, you're right. A simple Google search got me to http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html which turns out to be the 1.8.6 documentation; I hadn't checked the 1.8.7 docs.

Comment: Ahhh, that's where I was going wrong. I didn't realize there were 1.8.7 docs.

Answer (score 1):

It is documented [here](http://ruby-doc.org/ruby-1.9/classes/String.html#M000606).

Answer (score 0):

Rails' ActiveSupport had originally monkeypatched `String#chars` as well. Were they using Rails or ActiveSupport in the answer?

Comment: They weren't. It was regular ruby. But I think this monkey patching is something I need to look into some more.